# Distribution of number of heads by coin flipped a geometric number of times

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, geometric-distribution

I have random variables $N \sim \text{geo}(p)$, and $B | N \sim \text{bin}(N, q)$. I'm looking for the distribution of $B$. To be clear, I have

$$
\mathbb{P}(N=n) = p(1-p)^n \quad \text{for } n = 0, 1, 2, \dots
$$
$$
\mathbb{P}(B=b\mid N=n) = {n \choose b}q^b(1-q)^{n-b} \quad \text{for }b = 0, 1, \dots n
$$
and I am having trouble evaluating

$$
\mathbb{P}(B=b) = \sum_{n=b}^\infty \mathbb{P}(B=b\mid N=n)\mathbb{P}(N=n)
$$

Comment: Your question is unclear -- *which* geometric? The number of trials version (from 1 up) or the number of successes version (0 up)? Note that WIkipedia presents both. I presume you intend the number of trials version but you should make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}(B=b) &= \sum_{n=b}^\infty \mathbb{P}(B=b\mid N=n)\mathbb{P}(N=n) \\
&= \sum_{n=b}^\infty{n \choose b}q^b(1-q)^{n-b}p(1-p)^n \\
&= \sum_{l=0}^\infty{b+l \choose b}q^b(1-q)^lp(1-p)^{b+l} \\
&= p(q(1-p))^b\sum_{l=0}^\infty{b+l \choose l}((1-q)(1-p))^l \\
&= \frac{p(q(1-p))^b}{(1 - (1-q)(1-p))^{b+1}}\sum_{l=0}^\infty{b+l \choose l}(1-(1-q)(1-p))^{b+1}((1-q)(1-p))^l \\
&= \frac{p(q(1-p))^b}{(1 - (1-q)(1-p))^{b+1}} \\
&= \left(\frac{p}{p+q-pq}\right)\left(1 - \frac{p}{p+q-pq}\right)^b
\end{split}
$$

Where the sum on line 5 disappeared because it is a sum over the pmf of a negative binomial.

So we see $B$ is geometric with parameter $\frac{p}{p+q-pq}$.